# SQL: Automatic numbering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a question about SQL language which I couldn't find an answer for. I want SQL to automatically insert a number based off how much rows there are. Using an ASP.NET website I'm adding new rows and deleting rows. This means when I delete rows I want the table to automatically respond to that.

It is pretty hard to explain for me, so I already did some thinking ofcourse. I can fill it in using a C# code but when a row is deleted it ofcourse does not automatically change.

```
if (kisten < 4)
{
    staple = 1;
}
else
{
    if (staple1 >= 4)
    {
        staple = stapel2 + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        stapel = stapel2;
    }
}
```

So what this means is that one staple contains 4 blocks. But I want if one row gets removed from the staple the first row of the second staple gets added to the first staple, so it gets value '1'.
Hope I am clear enough. If not, please don't hesitate to ask.

EDIT:

I am using SQL Server indeed. Here is a clear example of what I mean:

[This is when everything is inserted using C# and as u can see it works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7hZb.png)

[This is when rows get deleted. As you can see the column 'Stapel' does not automatically change the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x6ZO.png)

[What I want when rows get deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CQ4a.png)

So after hours of trying I found a solution which works perfectly. Like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd11 = new SqlCommand("select count(kistid) from [dbo].[kist] where rij = '" + rij + "'", con);
int countrij = (Int32)cmd11.ExecuteScalar();
int procent = (4 / countrij * 100);
int hoeveel;
int hoeveel2 = (countrij % 4);
int hoeveel1;
if (hoeveel2 == 0)
{
    hoeveel = (countrij / 4);
    hoeveel1 = hoeveel;
    for (int i = 0; i < hoeveel; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlquery5 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TOP (" + countrij + ") Kist SET Stapel ='" + hoeveel1 + "' WHERE Rij ='" + rij + "'");
        sqlquery5.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlquery5.Connection = con;
        sqlquery5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        hoeveel1 = hoeveel1 - 1;
        countrij = countrij - 4;
    }
}
else
{
    hoeveel = ((countrij - hoeveel2) / 4) + 1;
    hoeveel1 = hoeveel;
    for (int i = 0; i < hoeveel; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlquery5 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TOP (" + countrij + ") Kist SET Stapel ='" + hoeveel1 + "' WHERE Rij ='" + rij + "'");
        sqlquery5.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlquery5.Connection = con;
        sqlquery5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        hoeveel1 = hoeveel1 - 1;
        countrij = countrij - hoeveel2;
        hoeveel2 = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to automatically re-calculate the sequence when rows are removed, you're probably better off using something like the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function that storing it in the database. Can you perhaps add some before / after sample data so that we can better understand what you're hoping to achieve? Also worth clarifying which database engine you're using - I've assumed SQL Server, but would be good to clarify.

Comment: @LucSil . . . Your question would make much more sense if you provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.  I don't even know what you mean by "insert a number".  In SQL, one inserts *rows* into *tables*.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I just added that. Hope you could help. Thanks.

Comment: I'd do this in your query. This is a dynamic result, not something it sounds like you need to persist in the database.

Comment: Hi, @Charleh I found already a solution as you can see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically do something in a database when `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `INSERT` command is executed for a given table you have to use `CREATE TRIGGER` to define a new trigger.

For more information just read about usage of triggers in your specific database server. For example for SQL Server you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did some thinking and read about triggers couldn't really find an answer to my question. There is no such query that selects the first 4 rows and than moves on to the 5-8 rows and  so on. If you got an idea please help me because i'm pretty much stuck here..